# assigning mongoose result feild value to vriable in express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i am trying to assign value of a feild from momgoose to a variable which would be used as value to another feild in another schema which is as follows.

```
function getNextSequence() {
    var x = null
    relcounter.findOne({"name":"cabi"},'seq',  function (err, configs) {
    x=configs.seq
     console.log("##"+x)
     })
     console.log(x)

}
```

X is coming out to be null 
Also i need this value of x to add to another feild which is as follows

```
relconf.update( 
                   {name:"css"},
                    { $push: { relations: {id:getNextSequence(),name:req.body.name,divId:"name_div"} } }
```

**Basically ineed the function getNextsequence to return the value of seq feild and assign to id feild**
can anyone suggest proper code and reason for null value for getNextSequence()

Comment: Hello. Can you show your output?

Comment: m getting null on printing x

Comment: its like: ##3 and null

Comment: The output is absolutely right. Node.js is asynchronous. So you can use callbacks or Promise.

Answer (score 0):

It useless wrap it in function, you must create include callbacks or Promises chaining. So you need read about asynchronous JavaScript https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-goes-asynchronous-awesome/ For example:

```
//callbacks example
...
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    //parse request params
    ...
    relcounter.findOne({"name": name},'seq',  function (err, configs) {
        if(err) {
           throw err;
        }

        res.send(configs.seq);
    });
});

//promise example
...
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    //parse request params
    ...
    relcounter.findOne({"name": name},'seq')
    .then(function(configs){
         res.send(configs.seq);
    })
    .catch(function(err)=>{
       throw err;
    })
});
```